# Having problems identifying the missing Web Parts from the GUID for Upgrade of 07 to SP2010?

Tags: web-part

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get Web Part name from GUID](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13110/get-web-part-name-from-guid)

I have ran the preupgrade checker.  I've also ran the enumallwebs command.  I have over a hundred different web parts missing, that the previous administrator didn't reference.  How do I match up specific Web Part GUIDs to the actual web parts?

Comment: The answer to this question should help you out: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13110/get-web-part-name-from-guid