# Which Web Parts should get installed in SP2010 Update?

Tags: web-part, upgrade, content-query-web-part, feature-upgrade

Per Dave Wise's answer(http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13110/get-web-part-name-from-guid): Thanks, that worked great. However, even though my SQL Query returned 9000 results, about 18 of the 50 GUIDs are still not in the list. What does that mean?

Also, how do I go about identifying features and eventhandlers?

Also, a number fo the GUIDs are specified for search, do I have to activiate these in SP2010 or do they come standard with Search Services?